# Exporting Visualforce page to Microsoft Word with nested lists ol li

Tags: visualforce, ms-word

I'm generating Pdf & Word document through old fashion way using VF page(The reason for not using any tool is because the content will be received from two different integration and customer wants it to be done without any license cost for any tool like s-doc/nintex etc)

I'm using single VF page to generate both Pdf / Word document and this is how I'm doing it

**pdf url** : /apex/TestPdfWord?type=pdf

**word url** : /apex/TestPdfWord?type=doc

[image]

**In Pdf it displays as expected with pointers like 1.1, 1.2, 1.2.1, 1.2.2 ........**
[image]

**But the same get's overriden to 1,2,3 in word document**
[image]

**How can I achieve 1.1, 1.1.1 , 1.1.2 format in word doc?**

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].  I suspect that Visualforce's Word conversion process does not support this, and remember that Visualforce is an older technology.  The easiest solution is to use a paid document generation tool that can use Word files as templates.

Comment: Please share some code snippets, as of now we are not able to help.